# How to use jose.4.j to output JWK set endpoint?

Tags: java, jose4j, jwk

I can see how to create new `Key`s with [jose.4.j](https://bitbucket.org/b_c/jose4j) but what I'm wondering is how to take an array of them and output a publicly accessible JSON list for use as part of the discovery endpoint in OiDC. Something like the [IETF draft example](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/draft-ietf-jose-json-web-key-41#page-25) ...

```
 {"keys":
   [
     {"kty":"EC",
      "crv":"P-256",
      "x":"MKBCTNIcKUSDii11ySs3526iDZ8AiTo7Tu6KPAqv7D4",
      "y":"4Etl6SRW2YiLUrN5vfvVHuhp7x8PxltmWWlbbM4IFyM",
      "use":"enc",
      "kid":"1"},

     {"kty":"RSA",
      "n": "0vx7agoebGcQSuuPiLJXZptN9nndrQmbXEps2aiAFbWhM78LhWx
 4cbbfAAtVT86zwu1RK7aPFFxuhDR1L6tSoc_BJECPebWKRXjBZCiFV4n3oknjhMs
 tn64tZ_2W-5JsGY4Hc5n9yBXArwl93lqt7_RN5w6Cf0h4QyQ5v-65YGjQR0_FDW2
 QvzqY368QQMicAtaSqzs8KJZgnYb9c7d0zgdAZHzu6qMQvRL5hajrn1n91CbOpbI
 SD08qNLyrdkt-bFTWhAI4vMQFh6WeZu0fM4lFd2NcRwr3XPksINHaQ-G_xBniIqb
 w0Ls1jF44-csFCur-kEgU8awapJzKnqDKgw",
      "e":"AQAB",
      "alg":"RS256",
      "kid":"2011-04-29"}
   ]
 }
```

I imagine there's something obvious I'm missing like a `toString()` that doesn't show the private key?

Comment: P.S. -- Sometimes it helps me to ask a question on StackOverflow to get my brain thinking in the right direction ... so I apologize for this obviously very silly question

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's a `String toJson(JsonWebKey.OutputControlLevel outputControlLevel)` method on `JsonWebKeySet` that will only include the public parts when called with `JsonWebKey.OutputControlLevel.PUBLIC_ONLY`. That should give you what you're looking for. `JsonWebKeySet` can be instantiated with a list of JsonWebKeys.

Something like this, for example,

```
    RsaJsonWebKey rsaJwk1 = RsaJwkGenerator.generateJwk(2048);
    RsaJsonWebKey rsaJwk2 = RsaJwkGenerator.generateJwk(2048);
    EllipticCurveJsonWebKey ecJwk = EcJwkGenerator.generateJwk(EllipticCurves.P256);

    JsonWebKeySet jwks = new JsonWebKeySet(rsaJwk1, rsaJwk2, ecJwk);

    String jwksJson = jwks.toJson(JsonWebKey.OutputControlLevel.PUBLIC_ONLY);

    System.out.println(jwksJson);
```

Would give,

```
{"keys":[{"kty":"RSA","n":"4cejS2CzkJuoLe9ry1JDdS_-RkpR2UMLialeH9WleuQFbFT3caK-GtNwObcd9_xEZ2H7um2GgZuscCMepo7d0FmwQUnfnTy9-_ckdgvVCH6lF62H3Jd4FBWAlcp_100kEJUe9YwfytdJ0zpOLo5Q38kH31cyMZmZRfexf33CzMNhlgE3mydpM9NAOAnR8IXW43tl1lPEy_dvLE9kM4idIjhd5Xd0a_YmRr05PK4UgFot0cuzZgu0HHe1qM7aFevwSOQ_Y86g4ofjZWHQWGJRN6WCBlGLscUwB52-hlJC0GrVEI0Cb55bfAfu01P1eFTjwyjfwggyLFZLdiAkZl2Jkw","e":"AQAB"},{"kty":"RSA","n":"jyOndkwyHBaHMn1xTIPfKV8PulJi6lcqqnw3sOabE-hClQr6De_OEcMnfCHPuogz1oep0A7-SvjY6Lclp0Pa5JDnHy6fI8UkSmASS6cwEUVWg18taFazRu2GtKDmMzT0Sh7ZCRGLWU74p5hRHGCerVnLcJUqSzT7kuGViZWVaIt00SfI6OImDpJTnaoxSwasdrhIZ_j5ARM93B2RKFsEb1kZ_gPnlP_0Qzs62LLG-78QQzlfMTd6v29vNr1FPPeZe744ni5Rpp19vEfEShGSV6Vz8K_Z2JlYC8PA_cRx47FLvmj9fB1u_wWYNP5ryGjv2E5Vjy9tqnIOmmtByoTdFw","e":"AQAB"},{"kty":"EC","x":"EEzQrpMmJ4XQgJFNGFNVI2WLmoaIpMYBTNF1_D5lp2U","y":"rENpzGhayZRoVR-7cFWJKElDQdJkJrKrDJ0-FqNpstA","crv":"P-256"}]}
```